# How do you drag and delete ??? but only when you touch that red bin button given in https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHCtG.jpg

Tags: ios, swift

I have a sticker which is draggable as I drag it and while dragging it when my finger reaches below the white board and that delete imageview appears and when I have reached there location. How do I detect touch on that imageview.

I am using pan gesture for dragging and pinch and rotation gestures also at the same time. But how will I know that I have touched my delete ImageView

Here is the image which has a stickerView on the back which is draggable and has a delete imageView on the front of the stickerView which is fixed.

[image]

```swift
    @objc func handlePanGesture(_ gestureRecognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        switch gestureRecognizer.state {
        case .began:
            // panGestureInStickerViewClosure?(true)
            break
        case .changed:
           // panGestureInStickerViewClosure?(true)
            let deleteImageView = gestureRecognizer.view?.superview?.subviews.filter{$0.isKind(of: UIImageView.self)}[safe: 0]
            deleteImageView?.addGestureRecognizer(BlockGestureRecognizer())
            let stickerImageViewFrame = gestureRecognizer.view?.superview?.subviews.filter{$0.isKind(of: HBStickerView.self)}[safe: 0]
            let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self)
            print("translation=\(translation),deleteImageView?.frame=\(deleteImageView?.frame),stickerImageViewFrame?.frame=\(stickerImageViewFrame?.frame)")
            break
        case .ended:
            break
        default:
            break
        }
        print(gestureRecognizer.numberOfTouches)
        if gestureRecognizer.numberOfTouches == 1{
            panGestureInStickerViewClosure?(true)
        }else if gestureRecognizer.numberOfTouches > 1{
            panGestureInStickerViewClosure?(false)
        }
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.superview)
        self.center = CGPoint(x: self.center.x + translation.x, y: self.center.y + translation.y)
        gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.superview)
        print(gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.superview))
        //print("self.frame.maxY=\(self.frame.maxY),self.superview?.frame.maxY=\(self.superview?.frame.maxY),self.center=\(self.center),gestureRecognizer.location(in: self)=\(gestureRecognizer.location(in: self))")
       // panGestureInStickerViewClosure?(true)
    }
```

I have above code written for pan gesture
I am using this gesture recognizer for panning. But getting translation location also does not work for me. If I can get the gesture location for my thumb or any finger and perform my need.

All I want to get touch event on that delete ImageView in front of all Subview while I am dragging the StickerView below that Subview.

Let me give you an example of Instagram. An Instagram has stickers which you can drag around and pinch and rotate and when it comes to deleting you have to touch on that delete button then the delete button gets scaled to max size and StickerView gets to scaled-down and finally is removed from the superView.